# Python file with dot is getting run without my updates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a file.py program. But when i run it through cmd with python3 file.py, I see in my text editor a new file called ".file.py" gets made and run instead. This file has none of my changes, so whatever I change to file.py is not run.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you are in the directory where you have your file (use dir and it will show you all the files in the folder you are in) once you have done that just run `python file.py` and your program should run.

to make sure cmd is in the folder you want, put cmd in the bar above where the path to your current folder is shown.

Comment: yes i have tried that, im not sure why it is still running the old file